# printf-ing an object returned by reference unexpectedly doesn't produce garbage

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

As an exercise I'm writing a class kind of similar to `std::lock_guard<>` that wraps a class `T`. I added a `data` method that returns the wrapped thing by reference.

I tested it with a wrapped integer and tried passing the integer to `printf("%d\n, ...")`, bypassing the type system to some extent. I expected to see garbage, or a pointer, or the first half of a pointer because of width issues, or a crash, or something.

To my surprise, the code worked as expected ... which suggests that my model of how returning by reference works is wrong ... or that there's undefined behavior here and the code just happened to work but isn't guaranteed to.

Is it okay to treat a thing-returned-by-reference as an instance of the actual thing when passing it to a C-style variadic function like `printf`?

Here's a stripped down version of the code with just the relevant methods and fields.

```
#include <cstdio>

struct int_holder {
public:
    int m_data{27};
public:
    int& data() {
        return this->m_data;
    }
};

int main() {
    int_holder h{};
    printf("%d\n", h.data());
}
```

I tested it using MinGW on Windows 10.

```
$ g++ -Wall -Werror -pedantic -std=c++11 .\return_int_by_ref.cpp
$ .\a.exe
27
```

Comment: Everything is initialized and there is no undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`printf()` does not take any parameters by reference, only by value. So, even though `data()` returns an `int&` reference, passing that reference to `printf()` will pass the *value* of the `int` being referenced, not the reference itself.  And `%d` expects an `int` value, so all is good, no garbage is outputted.

This is NOT undefined behavior. This is how passing a reference to a pass-by-value parameter is *supposed* to work, it is very much defined behavior.  It is essentially doing this:

```
int &ref = h.data();
int value = ref;
printf("%d\n", value);
```

Comment: Is it possible to create a badly behaved version of `printf` that is not reference-aware?

Comment: It is certainly possible to make `printf()` behave badly, simply pass it a malformed format string. But `printf()` itself is not reference-aware to begin with.  All of its parameters are pass-by-value, so it is the compiler itself that is dereferencing the reference when preparing the stack frame to call into `printf()`.

Comment: So the anonymous "parameter slots" in the trailing part of `printf`'s signature, despite being untyped, still inherently capture things by value. That's amazing. References are way more baked into C++ than I realized.

Comment: References are just aliases (though they are commonly *implemented* by most compilers using pointers), so you are really passing the original `int` to `printf()`, not a reference to the `int`. References are a core piece of the C++ language.